# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable, selectlistitem

I have a method in my controller:

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(EngineOIRemovalsViewModel model)
{                     
    model.MajSecList = db.EngineOIRFRs.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.MajorSection.ToString(), Text = m.MajorSection });
    if (model.SelectedMajorSection != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<EngineOIRFR> Areas = db.EngineOIRFRs.Where(l => l.MajorSection == model.SelectedMajorSection);
        model.AreaList = new SelectList(Areas);
    }
    else
    {
        model.AreaList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
    if (model.SelectedArea != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<EngineOIRFR> SubAreas = db.EngineOIRFRs.Where(l => l.Area == model.SelectedArea);
        model.SubAreaList = new SelectList(SubAreas);
    }
    else
    {
        model.SubAreaList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
    if (model.SelectedArea != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<EngineOIRFR> Failures = db.EngineOIRFRs.Where(l => l.SubArea == model.SelectedSubArea);
        model.FailureList = new SelectList(Failures);
    }
    else
    {
        model.FailureList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error, from the title, in the below line:

```
model.MajSecList = db.EngineOIRFRs.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.MajorSection.ToString(), Text = m.MajorSection });
```

It says an explicit conversion exists for this, but so far my searching hasn't been able to find one. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand this question. You are doing it correctly **right below the line with the error**

Comment: A `DropDownListFor() method expect an `IEnemerable<SelectListItem>` to generate the options. Your `FailureList` property should be just that (not `SelectList`, which is just a wrapper around `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: And if you use the `SelectList` constructor with a collection of complex objects, you also need to specify the property names to use for the options value and text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems (at least)

**First**, you are also not `Select`ing the right type. `MajSecList` is of type `SelectList`, but you are explicitly selecting `SelectListItem`. You will need to update your `Select`.

**Second**, `Select` is not executed right away. You need to use something like `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault` (depending on what you need) to actually execute the query and return the result:

```
model.MajSecList = db.EngineOIRFRs.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.MajorSection.ToString(), Text = m.MajorSection }).ToList();
```

The idea is that you can build a query, chaining together operations like `Select` or `Where`, etc. without performing the query each time.

Once you're done building your query and use `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` (or others), it actually performs the query and returns the results.

Or just do what you're doing below that, and pass the query to the constructor of `SelectList`:

```
model.MajSecList = new SelectList(db.EngineOIRFRs.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.MajorSection.ToString(), Text = m.MajorSection }));
```

Comment: Actually, the OP needs a collection, not the first item. This also doesn't solve the problem as `SelectListItem` is not `SelectList`

Comment: Also, notice that the OP is doing it correctly right below the incorrect line, and this answer should match that

Comment: @GabrielLuci that last edit seems like the correct answer to me.

Comment: @GabrielLuci , adding .ToList() to the end gave a different error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collects.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'  but passing the query to the constructor of SelectList per your other suggestion worked out! Thank you all very much!

Comment: Your last line of code is wrong - (and in the view will generate all the options with the text and value being `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"`)